# Find MongoDB Document, that has parameter in last item in array

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

i need help to build a query in Spring Boot for mongoDB.

This is my Document Structure:

```json
{
"stateHistory": [
    {
      "taskState": "DONE"
    },
    {
      "taskState": "START"
    },
    {
      "taskState": "FINISH"
    }
  ],
}
```

I defined already this query, it is returning all Documents, that have in any position of the array stateHistory a taskState that is in the given Array anyTaskStateIn.

```java
query.addCriteria(new Criteria().andOperator(
Criteria.where("stateHistory").elemMatch(Criteria.where("taskState").in(anyTaskStateIn))));
```

Now i want a Query, that is returning all Documents, that has as last value in stateHistory the taskState, that is in the given array lastTaskStateIn.

In JavaScript i would write it like this:

```js
if(stateHistory[stateHistory.length -1].taskState in lastTaskStateIn){
   return
}
```

In my example document, it would returne the document if the given array lastTaskStateIn would look like this ["FINISH"]
And it would not return, if it look like this ["DONE", "START"]

Thanks for your help <3

Answer (score 0):

The query with mongo playground:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/Pp6p7jAimBJ

---

Code with Spring data

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "stateHistory")
public class DocumentStateHistory {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private List<StateHistory> stateHistory;

    @Data
    @Builder
    public static class StateHistory {
        private String taskState;
    }

}
```

--

```
public List<DocumentStateHistory.StateHistory> getTaskStateIn(List<String> lastTaskStateIn) {

        final var stateHistoryField = "stateHistory";

        var basicProjectStage = project(stateHistoryField).and(stateHistoryField).arrayElementAt(-1).as("lastElt");

        ConditionalOperators.Cond condOperation = ConditionalOperators.when(Criteria.where("lastElt.taskState").in(lastTaskStateIn))
                                                                        .thenValueOf(stateHistoryField)
                                                                        .otherwise(Collections.emptyList());
        var secondProjectStage = project().and(condOperation).as(stateHistoryField);


        var aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(basicProjectStage, secondProjectStage, unwind(stateHistoryField), replaceRoot(stateHistoryField));
        AggregationResults<DocumentStateHistory.StateHistory> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, DocumentStateHistory.class, DocumentStateHistory.StateHistory.class);

        return results.getMappedResults();
    }
```

--

- **Case 1: lastTaskStateIn: ["FINISH"]**

  ```
  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
   var lastTaskStateIn = List.of("FINISH");
   var aggregationResults = getTaskStateIn(lastTaskStateIn);
   log.info("Result => {}", aggregationResults);
  }
  ```

> Result => [DocumentStateHistory.StateHistory(taskState=DONE),
> DocumentStateHistory.StateHistory(taskState=START),
> DocumentStateHistory.StateHistory(taskState=FINISH)]

--

- **Case 2: lastTaskStateIn: ["DONE", "START"]**

  ```
  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
   var lastTaskStateIn = List.of("FINISH");
   var aggregationResults = getTaskStateIn(lastTaskStateIn);
   log.info("Result => {}", aggregationResults);
  }
  ```

> Result => []